# BroadcastReceiver context with dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to achieve the following

1. An Activity starts a background task (SyncAdapter) and shows a dialog.
2. The background task sends broadcasts.
3. These broadcasts should be intercepted by the dialog.

What I would expect is this:

```
Dialog           Broadcast
  <-------------------
 OK!
  <-------------------
 OK!

         ....

  <-------------------
 OK!
```

But what I get is this:

```
Dialog           Broadcast
  <-------------------
  <-------------------

         ....

  <-------------------

    (dialog dismiss)

 OK!
 OK!

         ....
 OK!
```

As the diagram shows, the broadcasts are being sent correctly, but they are being received only after the dialog is dismissed. I want to receive them when the dialog is being shown. In other words, steps 1 and 2 are working fine, but 3. is working partially. What I think might be the problem is that I'm not using the proper context for the BroadcastReceiver.

So my question is: Which context should I use to subscribe for updates (i.e. receive the broadcasts, not send them), so that they can be picked up by the dialog when it is being shown?

I've tried with `Activity.this`, `Activity.this.getBaseContext()` and  `Activity.this.getApplicationContext()`, `dialog.getContext()`, `DialogFragment.getActivity()` to no avail.

Just to clarify: I've used the BroadcastReceiver pattern multiple times, I'm just having trouble when using it alongside a dialog.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with `Activity`, will edit accordingly.

Comment: "These broadcasts should be intercepted by the dialog." should maybe be "These broadcasts should be intercepted by the Activity than than dismisses the Dialog"? Or please specify what `Context` you want to use for?

Comment: Are you running a service to send broadcasts?  An AlarmManager?

Comment: I'm sending them through a SyncAdapter

Comment: So you're trying to figure out which context for this:     public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    }

Comment: No, because the SyncAdapter sends the broadcast, I want to know which context to use to receive them properly.

Comment: You're sending a broadcast through the sync adapter, wouldn't you use it as the context?

Comment: Sending broadcasts is not a problem, but receiving them is...

Answer (score 1):

**FACTS:**

- ACTIVITY (A) shows DIALOG (D)
- unknown type of (SOMETHING) named BACKGROUND TASK (T)
- (T) SENDS BROADCAST TO BROADCASTRECEIVER (R)
- (R) SHOULD DISMISS (D)

**QUESTIONS:**

- (T) do you mean CLASS DERIVED from AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter?
- do you somehow finish (A) after start of (T) and show (D)?

**CONCLUSION:**

- regardless what you do if your (A) create and shows (D) it is responsible to dismiss (D) & to do it before gets in onStop() state
- other words if activity will die without dismissed dialog you will get

> ```
> android.view.WindowLeaked exception will be thrown.
> ```

- & when you try manipulate the dialog you will get:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
> ```

**The second part** of your question, which concerns **context**

- you always can check which context is assigned to Dialog by method

> ```
> Dialog.getContext()
> ```

- usen it to match other context

> ```
> Dialog.getContext().equals(Context);
> ```

- also u can use Class method

> ```
> Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> c)
> ```

- if u wanna match context to class (for example Activity  u use)

> ```
> MyActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(ObjectToMatch.getClass());
> ```

and I would forget to add:

you can always **START DIALOG USING APPLICATION CONTEXT :)**

& one more thing:

**any stuff involving UI should by done on UI THREAD**  in case you will forgot & get

> ```
> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> ```

**edit:**

I DON'T SEE ANY PROBLEM : **WORKING SOLUTION**

[image: THREAD CALLING RECEIVER]

Comment: Question 1: Yes. Question 2: No, the activity remains visible throughout the whole process.

Comment: @jlhonora are u sure ? do u logging ?  do you want to receive broadcasts from outside the application.? or within?

Comment: Yes, all logged. Within the app. I know, it's very strange. Just when the dialog is dismissed I receive the broadcasts in burst.

Comment: so what u want to achieve exactly?

Comment: To receive the broadcasts meanwhile the dialog is shown, not after it is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `BroadcastReceiver` and you adapt it on your code. Instead of `Activity.this`, `Activity.this.getBaseContext()` and  `Activity.this.getApplicationContext()` you should use `Context` like this :

```
class BroadCastReceiverTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    this.context = c;

}
```

Now you have to use `this.context` as a `Context`.

Comment: Yes, but which context should I use to subscribe for updates?

Comment: This `this.context` as I said

Comment: That doesn't make sense, I can only access that context when I do receive the broadcast. So what you're proposing is a catch-22.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Otto**

https://github.com/square/otto

From documentation,

> An enhanced Guava-based event bus with emphasis on Android support.
>
> Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your
>   application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.
>
> Forked from Guava, Otto adds unique functionality to an already
>   refined event bus as well as specializing it to the Android platform.

Comment: omg for what do u need it ? There was a little Story whose action taken place in Activity Thread (aka UI Thread)  kingtom;. -Hi  I'm mighty Looper )  <== in meanwhile... knock knock!  -who is it?  It's me Handler!  ok come  on in my friend -May I with my friend Runnable? -Yes you both are welcome! :)