# beginner* - Make android WebView reload on interval

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm new to Android and Java. I managed to build a very simple WebView app and i've been trying to make it refresh the provided url on certain interval.
Here's my code, how do i change it?:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String url = "https://mywebsite.com/";
        view.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

Comment: I know this might be a duplicate but i just couldn't figure out how it works, looking at other answers

Comment: I know, i already said that.

Comment: that was an automatic comment made by the flag....

Answer (score 1):

```
/** timer */
private Timer _timer;

/** timer task interval rate */
private int _rate;

/** timer task */
privat TimerTask _timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /**your web view routines  */

                    }
                }
            });
      };

/** set timer method */
private void setTask() {
    /** check if timer was already not set */
    if(_timer!=null) {
        /** then just return */
        return;
    }
    /** create timer */
    _timer = new Timer();
    /** set rate */
    _rate = 1000; // repeat interval in ms
    /** schedule timer task */
    _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(_timerTask, 0, _rate);
}

/** cancel timer method */
private void cancelTask() {
     /** check for timer */
     if (_timer != null) {
        /** disable timer schedule */
        _timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

i'm pointing out that @mattfred solution is for single! execution of task & will fail on call from outside Activity Thread besides calling his set method from onCreate() is waste of resources (see: on saved instance state)

ps. read also this to **avoid errors on manipulate widgets especially when using TIMER** !!!

[any stuff involving UI shoul by done on UI THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186540/broadcastreceiver-context-with-dialog/31189243#31189243)

ps2.

A simple **schedule()** method will execute at once while **scheduleAtFixedRate()** method takes and extra parameter which is for repetition of the task again & again on specific time interval.

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but I just started working with android and Java for the first time today and I would need a bit more detailed guide since I've only worked with php js html etc. for now

Comment: @RaTre u free to ask

Comment: Are you willing to help me build a simple auto refresh webview app from the ground up? It shouldn't be much work for advanced developer.. I would be grateful

Comment: Take pencil and write down detailed diagram / picture what u wanna achieve, how should it look like and work then we can write code. Send scan to my email from there we will be in touch now its 3'o at night at my local

Comment: Hey! Sorry i couldn't get back to that sooner. The app i need is real simple. Just a fullscreen WebView with refresh on interval. Can i message you somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not to struggle with the Java code itself I suggetst doing it by javascript.
Simply do a location.reload() after a while the page loads like :

```
setTimeout(function(){
location.reload()
},seconds*1000)
```

Comment: Good suggestion but I want to use the app to send status and location with every update. And since I know no other way I'll try to gather information for that using android's built in features and send it over to my php and js with GET method where I can handle better.